# what are the differences between Rational rose and Netbeans ?

Tags: netbeans, uml, rational-rose

i am a bigenner in modeling design like UML and i want to know what are the features of rational rose and netbeans and what are the differences between these two .thanks for advance;
.

Answer (score 0):

1. Netbeans is IDE. It **had** support of standard UML and **has not** any UML for the last 2 versions. The free plugin of Visual Paradigm is not free anymore and belongs to VP UML now, not to NB.
2. Rational is Modelling tool and **had** and **has** UML support. But **very** far from standard.

BOTH are not suitable for work in UML. You can use Rational for modelling if you are a masochist. But do not forget - it is **not** UML.